# Automated way of converting Selenium HTML tests to JUnit?

Tags: selenium, junit, automated-tests

I'm using Selenium IDE 1.0.10 for Firefox on Mac 10.6.6.  Our QA department has created some HTML tests for Selenium that I need to convert to Junit.  In the IDE, I can do that by going to the File menu and choosing export.  What is an automated/scriptable way to do this same task?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951136/automated-way-of-converting-selenium-html-tests-to-junit

Answer (score 1):

Try this add in. I have not used it, but it is described just as you need it. [Addin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/test-suite-batch-converter-sel/?src=api)

Answer (score 1):

Try this addon which converts Selenium HTML scripts to Java .

[Selenium4J](http://code.google.com/p/selenium4j/)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the selenese4J-maven-plugin. Similar to selenium4j (https://github.com/RaphC/selenese4j-maven-plugin).

Provides many features :
Selenium 1/2 (WebDriver) conversion
Test Suite generation
Internationalisation of your html file
Possibility to use snippet into your html file for specific test (e.g : computing working day, write custom generation of values, handle dynamic values ...)
Use of tokenized properties

Answer (score 0):

I took the [selenium4j](http://code.google.com/p/selenium4j) project and turned it into a maven plugin for those who want to take the html test cases and automatically have them run with your maven test phase.  You can also separate the tests out using a profile override with surefire.

Readme is here: https://github.com/willwarren/selenium-maven-plugin

The short version of the readme:

Converts this folder structure:

```
./src/test/selenium
    |-signin
        |-TestLoginGoodPasswordSmoke.html
        |-TestLoginBadPasswordSmoke.html
        |-selenium4j.properties
```

Into

```
./src/test/java
    |-signin
        |-firefox
            |-TestLoginGoodPasswordSmoke.java
            |-TestLoginBadPasswordSmoke.java
```

This is only tested on windows with Firefox and Chrome.
I couldn't get the IE version to pass a test, but I'm new to selenium so hopefully, if you're a selenium guru, you can get past this.